# How to update angular component variable in 'then'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress, updates

I would like to wait till `angComponent.gridApi` does not have the value `undefined`.

I'm not sure, but I think the variable `angComponent` doesn't update.

```
cy.getAngularComponent(tableGrid).then((angComponent) => {
   cy.get(angComponent.gridApi).should('not.contain', undefined);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the variable `angComponent` does not update, you should change `.then()` to `.should()`. Cypress will retry it for you.

```js
cy.getAngularComponent(tableGrid)
  .should((angComponent) => {
    expect(angComponent.val()).not.to.eq('')
  })
```